Undefined Function in Shared library but not in object files
I have a shared library that when put through a nm call shows a undefined symbol for strerror@@GLIBC_2.2.5.
However, when I go through all object files that this shared library was generated from, and dump their symbols, using objdump, I do not see this symbol show up.
The source code does not explicitly use std:strerror either
In what cases could this happen?
How could I find the source code that results in the necessity of this strerror symbol?

Perhaps some function in the library calls a function in some other library, that then calls strerror? Linking the standard library last might be a solution.

Can you create a [mcve]?  Remove as much stuff as you can from your code until you have a minimal example that shows the problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


However, when I go through all object files that this shared library was generated from, and dump their symbols, using objdump, I do not see this symbol show up.

When you link your shared library, the compiler driver adds some object files of its own to the link line (e.g. crti.o, crtbeginS.o, etc.). Adding -Wl,-v to the link line should show that happening.
You can tell where the reference to strerror is coming from by asking the linker: add -Wl,-y,strerror to your link line.
